# How to get the input text value and set it to span text using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, add-this-event

I have a form with some input elements like text, dropdown, radiobuttons, etc in my html page. I want to get the entered value in the input text element, selected value or text in the dropdown element (and so on based on input elements type) and set them to text or value of different span elements before submitting the form? I need it as I am trying to implement addthisevent button on my form so that users will be able to save information to their calendar before submitting the form.

Comment: can you show what you have so far?

Comment: Please share the code.

Comment: If you don't show us your (relevant) HTML and attempted jQuery, what would you like us to do? Guess at your structure? Because, while guessing games can be fun, they're not productive when it comes to implementing those guesses in your production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the Addthisevent button dynamically through jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){

   $('.button1').click(function(){

   var text=$('.mytext').val();

   $('.box').html(text);

    });

    });


    </script>

    </head>
     <body>

      <input type="text" class="mytext"></input>

      <div class="button1" id="a1">button1</div>


       <span class="box"></span>


      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Your code is similar to mine. But it is not working in the addthisevent click.